# How to merge dataframes correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframes to merge:

```
    first = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': [1, 2],
        'time': [1, 2]
    })
    second = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': [2, 3],
        'time': [3, 4]
    })
    third = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': [3, 4],
        'time': [5, 6]
    })

    first.merge(second, on='id', how='outer', suffixes=('', 2)).merge(third, on='id', how='outer', suffixes=('', 3))
```

What i have:

```
    id  time  time2  time3
0   1   1.0    NaN    NaN
1   2   2.0    3.0    NaN
2   3   NaN    4.0    5.0
3   4   NaN    NaN    6.0
```

How can I get this?:

```
    id  time  time2  time3
0   1   1.0    NaN    NaN
1   2   2.0    3.0    NaN
2   3   4.0    5.0    NaN
3   4   6.0    NaN    NaN
```

I need the value to move to the first empty column, so that in every row all the NaNs are on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your output by `transform` with `sorted`

```
df=df.transform(lambda x : sorted(x, key=pd.isnull),1)
Out[255]: 
    id  time  time2  time3
0  1.0   1.0    NaN    NaN
1  2.0   2.0    3.0    NaN
2  3.0   4.0    5.0    NaN
3  4.0   6.0    NaN    NaN
```